# License Key Management Database For Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

so I am planning on distributing software that requires a license key to activate the product. I was wondering what the best way to approach this was. I wrote the program in Java and have looked into several databases that would help me accomplish this, but have had no luck. 
Essentially, what I am trying to do is have something similar to a spreadsheet that would contain columns: Key, Email, Verified. The key tab would contain the key, email would contain email, and verified would contain a boolean of whether or not their product key had been activated yet, to make sure they do not share the product key and have 2 people under same product key at once. These are the databases I have tried:

1. Firebase

   - Great database but the java api only works for admin privileges, which i do not want to give to everyone using my program
2. MySQL

   - I tried a hosting service to host a MySQL database but could not succesfully connect to it.
3. GoogleSQL

   - Very similar to MySQL, but the github repo for the Java API seems incomplete and I get a class def not found error whenever i try to connect.

I have also tried https://airtable.com/ because it looked like something I could use, but the Java API again did not allow me to connect because of an issue using the API Key that was generated from the site.

If any of you could suggest a database to use that has a Java API or a different approach to my problem, I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What it seems you need is a "web service" through which your App can communicate with the data store - this way you added a level protection to your database

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your response!